# Как изменять выведенный текст в консоли посредством cout?

Tags: c++

Есть простая программа производящая долгие вычисления. Хотелось бы на каждой итерации цикла выводить ее номер (ну или текщий процент выполнения) в консоль, при этом желательно изменяя только последнюю строку. Например вывод

```
Start
Function result 45123
Testing ...
Comleted 45%
```

Так вот по ходу надо бы изменять только строку `Comleted 45%` а остальное не трогать. Вывод осуществляю через `cout`. Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот пример кода. sleep исключительно для того, что бы создать задержку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h> // для sleep
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+=10) {
        std::cout << "\rCompleted " << i << "%   " << std::flush;
        sleep(1);
    }

    std::cout << "\rDone            " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

std::flush нужен, так как стандартные потоки любят буферизировать ввод-вывод (закомментируйте и посмотрите на результат). `\r` переводит вывод в начало строки, не переходя на новую строку. Пара пробелов после процента нужна, так как строка не очищается и нужно затирать пробелами "хвост".

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Правда у меня все работает и без `std::flush`.

Comment: я думаю, это сильно зависит от используемой stl (разные компиляторы используют разные stl). Я тестил под gcc 4.8.3 на gentoo.

Comment: вместо нестандартного sleep, лучше использовать стандартный: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));` или `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);` для C++14

Answer (score 2):

вот еще способ. писал под windows но можно переписать и под линукс

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+=10) {
        system("cls"); // очистить терминал
        std::cout << "Completed " << i << "%" << std::endl;

        system("ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > c:\\111.txt"); // вместо ф-ии sleep которой у меня нет
    }

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ага, вот только cls чистит весь экран:)

Comment: да приходится воссоздавать элементы вывода каждый раз заново